# Query using IN clause and JOIN are possible in JpaRepository using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When i try to list elements in a JPQL or a Native Query, my list aways return 0 elements. When I do the query directly in the database, the query is ok:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT xml FROM CapturaXml xml  
            JOIN xml.capturaDados dados ON dados.chnfe = xml.chnfe   
            WHERE xml.chnfe IN (:chnfes) AND dados.capturaCerts.cnpj = :cnpj")  
Page<CapturaXml> findByCnpjInChnfes(@Param("cnpj") String cnpj, @Param("chnfes") List<String> chnfes, Pageable pageable);
```

Or this code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT xml FROM CAPTURA_XML xml  
            JOIN CAPTURA_DADOS dados ON dados.chnfe = xml.chnfe  
            WHERE dados.cnpj = :cnpj AND xml.chnfe IN (:chnfes)",  
nativeQuery = true)  Page<CapturaXml> findByCnpjInChnfes(@Param("cnpj") String cnpj, @Param("chnfes") List<String> chnfes, Pageable pageable);
```

My test:

```
@Test
    public void testBuscarPorCnpjEChnfes() {
        List<String> chnfes = Arrays.asList(CHNFE1, CHNFE2, CHNFE3, CHNFE4);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PageRequest page = new PageRequest(0, 10);
        Page<CapturaXml> xmls = this.capturaXmlRepository.findByCnpjInChnfes(CNPJ, chnfes, page);

        assertEquals(4, xmls.getTotalElements());
    }
```

My test aways list 0 elements, but when I put a `List<CapturaXml> list = this.capturaXmlRepository.findAll();` the elements are inside the list.

What's the problem with my Queries?

**Obs:**
1: I tried to make the Fetch Eager, but not solved the problem.

Comment: No "ON dados.chnfe = xml.chnfe" should be in JPQL, it knows to do that automatically and doing so yourself causes problems.

Comment: @K.Nicholas thanks, but I tested without the ON clause and the problem persists. I have other Query with the ON clause and it works fine.

Comment: Well, you have several conditionals so not possible to evaluate question without knowing which conditionals are preventing desired results. Best bet is to print the SQL and run it by hand against the DB and determine what the issue is that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check Spring Data version and package of used @Query. Spring Data uses its own @Query annotation.